# I Built A Simple Product Filtering Feature - Questioning Robustness, Conventionality, JS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, filtering, bigcommerce

I built a simple product filtering feature that works at least in the browsers and platforms that I have tried using it on, but I am unsure about a couple of things.  I built this on a Bigcommerce site but I think my questions could still apply broadly (some):

1 - Is this a solid approach?  Conventional?  If not, why, and how could/should I approach it differently?

2 - Should I expect to have any problems with browser compatibility?  If so, would they be different problems than any problems I might experience if I was using the stock Bigcommerce faceted search option?

-Assume an out of the box faceted search option is not an available

-jQuery is loaded twice in HTMLhead.html (head template) as 1.7.2 and 2.2.2

The following example is a simplified version of what I created.  In this example there are only 4 products and 2 categories present.  We can also assume that no products belong in more than one category:

**HTML** - (Two checkboxes, one for each category)

```
<fieldset>
    <div class="col-md-6 test-one"><label><input id="example-category-1" type="checkbox" value="first-checkbox" />CHOOSE CATEGORY 1</label></div>
    <div class="col-md-6 test-one"><label><input id="example-category-2" type="checkbox" value="second-checkbox" />CHOOSE CATEGOYR 2</label></div>
</fieldset>
```

**HTML** - [fiddle with expanded li showing the structure of a random example product.](https://jsfiddle.net/s41fx7hh/)

**JS:**
--Page loads, all products present, no checkboxes clicked
--When a checkbox is clicked for the first time, all products are hidden (rather, their parent li's are)

```
    var test = true;
    $(".test-one").change(function() {
        if(test){           
            $('div[data-product]').parents("li").hide();
            //hide every product after first click on any checkbox 
            
            if( $('#example-category-1').is(':checked') ) {
            //check for checkbox activation and show products if true
                $('div[data-product="1802"]').parents("li").show();
                $('div[data-product="1781"]').parents("li").show();
            }
            if( $('#category-2').is(':checked') ) {
            //check for checkbox activation and show products if true
                $('div[data-product="1348"]').parents("li").show();
                $('div[data-product="1347"]').parents("li").show();
            }
            test =false;
            //set to false so we don't enter this if statement again
        }
    });
```

--For the rest of the time, this is what is handling the filtering (would like to exclude the following code from the first click, but seems to work okay as is):

```
$('#example-category-1').click(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $('div[data-product="1802"]').parents("li").show();
            $('div[data-product="1781"]').parents("li").show();
        } else {
            $('div[data-product="1802"]').parents("li").hide();
            $('div[data-product="1781"]').parents("li").hide();
        }
    });
    $('#example-category-2').click(function() {
        if( $(this).is(':checked') ) {
            $('div[data-product="1348"]').parents("li").show();
            $('div[data-product="1347"]').parents("li").show();
        } else {
            $('div[data-product="1348"]').parents("li").hide();
            $('div[data-product="1347"]').parents("li").hide();
        }
    });
```

Final Note:  I was told that I can manipulate the product object to achieve goals like this one - I kind of know in theory what the product object is, but I don't know how to access it / act on it - any input would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you very much for your time!

Comment: If you're not having a programming problem and your code works, the question should probably be directed to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: You should only have one version of jQuery active, else you can run into serious issues.